# Adding specific number at the end of a string until reach a specific total of characters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example of values from my `Column C`:

```
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186894151
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186867498
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.1869852
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986585
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986773
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.18698631
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186971962
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.18698667
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186973002
```

After the last `/` will always have the same amount of characters. But for some inexplicable reason the API is delivering the values without the zeros that exist to the right, so for example:

If the correct value is:

```
1.1011100
```

The value delivered is:

```
1.10111
```

So to adjust this I need to add the zeros to the right, for that I separate the last part of the value with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C1:C="","",RIGHT(C1:C,LEN(C1:C)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(C1:C,"/","*",LEN(C1:C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C1:C,"/","")))))))
```

The result is:

```
1.186894151
1.186867498
1.1869852
1.186986585
1.186986773
1.18698631
1.186971962
1.18698667
1.186973002
```

And to calculate the maximum number of characters that can be found, I use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN( FORMULA I PUT A LITTLE ABOVE IN QUESTION )))
```

The result in this case is `11`, so in all values there must be `11` characters after the last slash.

But now I don't know how I can add the zeros numbers that are missing from each value so that the result is:

```
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186894151
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186867498
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186985200
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986585
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986773
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986310
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186971962
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186986670
https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/football/market/1.186973002
```

What should I do to get this result?

Spreadsheet Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPnwwzFzN60G0rUjTgbBn5D5uIXaO-OTJtuHeKxCilw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided you 2 methods in the spreadsheet.

**`LEN`:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C1:C="",,C1:C&REPT("0",F1-LEN(E1:E))))
```

**`REGEXEXTRACT`:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C1:C="",,REGEXEXTRACT(C1:C&REPT("0",F1),".+\/.{"&F1&"}")))
```